# Function variable not showing up in xDebug with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug

So I have the following action in the controller. When Im using xDebug with Symfony 3 then the variables $request and $imNotBeingShowin is not shown in xDebug variable list. While variable $imBeingShown works fine when assigned to the class.

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
    $imNotBeingShown = 'why not?';

    $this->imBeingShown = 'wooot';
}
```

[image]

Any idea what is going on? I can't seem to find anything about this issue in Google.

/Hendrik

Edit: added an extra image for proof
[image]

Edit: app_dev.php variables are shown in debugger
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you were not inside the `saveAction` method when you were making this screenshot.

Comment: I was :). I just removed some code.

Comment: Can you make sure you are inside the function? Or share a screenshot with the breakpoint?

Comment: I have added an additional image, with code while debugging :). It is in the end of the original post

Comment: Collect xdebug log and see if it will be listed there (when you stop seeing it in PhpStorm) -- maybe xdebug does some optimisations for not-used-anywhere-later (and therefore useless) variables. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Answer (score 0):

> I have added an additional image, with code while debugging :).

This won't work. Once you've run your program it's loaded into memory. You can't change it on runtime.

Comment: Is there any work around? Because it will be pain in the ass to debug without seeing function variables.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your comment. I've read it as `I have added that  code while debugging` :). But you didn't, did you? Did you touched the code after you've started debugging?

Comment: The code was added before I started debugger :). For additional note: when i add a breakpoint in the app_dev.php, then variables in app_dev.php are shown properly in the debugger. Add also an image to the main post.